# local-map in header line

Tags: keymap, mode-line, header-line

I'm trying to have a clickable button in the header-line. The code below works for the mode-line but not for the header line. Is there something specific to add?

```
(setq-default header-line-format
 (list `(:propertize " ☰ "
                    face       mode-line-mode
                    mouse-face mode-line-highlight
                    local-map  ,mode-line-major-mode-keymap)
       `(:propertize "%m " face mode-line)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A click on the mode-line does not generate the event sequence `[mouse-1]` but `[mode-line mouse-1]` and similarly a click on the header line generates the sequence `[header-line mouse-1]`, so you need to tweak the `mode-line-major-mode-keymap` so it also reacts to event sequences like `[header-line mouse-1]`.
For example with:

```
(define-key mode-line-major-mode-keymap [header-line]
            (lookup-key mode-line-major-mode-keymap [mode-line]))
```