# how to copy top header line (`header-line-format`) under X

Tags: gui-emacs, header-line, gui, x-window

I have a header-line that displays currently opened file name on top of the buffer window. I can't find a way to copy the text/file name from that header-line **if emacs runs under X/gui** (*selecting with a mouse and coping it works fine under terminal*).
Does anyone have any suggestions?
(Perhaps there is a way to trigger an event by clicking on header-line so that could store file name so I could paste it into the terminal via mouse click as I usually do in -nw?)

[image]

Comment: It may also be possible to define a key for mouse-3 press on [header-line mouse-3] event https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47211/local-map-in-header-line

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this

[image: Filename in header-line]

and this

[image: Clicking on header-line copies it to kill-ring]

do this

```lisp
(add-hook
 'find-file-hook
 (defun my-find-file-hook ()
   (add-to-list
    'header-line-format
    '(:eval
      (let ((text (buffer-file-name)))
        (when text
          (buttonize
           text
           (lambda (text)
             (message "Copied `%s' to kill ring" text)
             (kill-new text))
           text
           "Click me, to copy me")))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked - although I've used it (`buttonize`) in `buffer-list-update-hook`.